# How to type a variable as any potential property from an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say you have an object which is of type MyObject:

```
type MyObject = {
   color: string;
   index: number;
   exists: boolean;
}

const obj = {
  color: 'blue',
  index: 1,
  exists: false
}
```

Say I then have a function that takes a param which is any of the properties in that obj:

```
const myFunction = (prop: string | number | false) => {
   //doSomething
}
```

Is there a way to reference MyObject type to define the type of prop? i.e:

```
const myFunction = (prop: ValuesOf<MyObject>) => {
   //doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define `MyObject`'s `exists` as `false`, not `boolean`, then you can use `MyObject[keyof MyObject]`:

```
type MyObject = {
    color: string;
    index: number;
    exists: false;
}
const myFunction = (prop: MyObject[keyof MyObject]) => {
    //doSomething
}
```

If your actual code both defines `MyObject` and `obj` at the same point, you can use `typeof` to make things less repetitive (though then the `exists` property will be typed as a boolean, not as false):

```
const obj = {
    color: 'blue',
    index: 1,
    exists: false
};
type MyObject = typeof obj;
const myFunction = (prop: MyObject[keyof MyObject]) => {
    //doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typeof` keyword to access the properties of an interface or class like [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64249615/14392422) pointed out.

But you can make it more syntactic sugar by using it as a generic

```
const myFunction = <T = keyof MyObject>(prop: T) => {
  //doSomething
}
```